# Combinatorics: Under-counting the probability of an outcome

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a computer science homework problem which deals with the probability of an input set being "ideal." I won't go into details about the application, but here is my mathematical understanding of it.

Consider a sorted list $L$ consisting of $n$ numbers. The numbers at from indices $n/4$ to $3n/4$ are considered "good" numbers. That means that if you select any element of $L$ at random, there is a $1/2$ chance it will be a "good" number, a $1/4$ chance it will be a "low bad" number, and a $1/4$ chance it will be a "high bad" number.

If I select 3 numbers from $L$ at random (repetitions are allowed), then what is the probability that the median of the three numbers will be a "good" number?

The way I see it, there are two bad cases and three good cases:

1. **BAD:** None of the numbers selected are in the "good" range. I initially calculated the probability of this to be
   $$
   \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{8}
   $$
2. **BAD:** One of the numbers selected is in the "good" range, but the other two numbers are both in the same "bad" range (either both "low bad" or both "high bad").
   $$
   \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \right) = \frac{1}{16}
   $$
3. **GOOD:** All of the numbers selected are in the "good" range.
   $$
   \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}
   $$
4. **GOOD:** Two of the selected numbers are in the "good" range.
   $$
   \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}
   $$
5. **GOOD:** Only one of the selected numbers is in the "good" range, but the other numbers are in opposite "bad" ranges.
   $$
   \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \right) = \frac{1}{16}
   $$

And here's where I'm stumped. The sum of these probabilities is $1/2$, and I don't believe there are any other cases to consider. I believe this might be solved with combinatorics, but all examples I have seen deal with equally-distributed sample sizes ("in a bag there are 4 balls of each of the following colours...") and I'm not sure how to translate the concept to this problem.

Comment: "GOOD: Two of the selected numbers are in the "good" range." why is this not 1/2*1/2*1/2? (I think you need the third to be outside the good range)

Comment: @AirConditioner good point, fixed

Comment: You need to multiply the the result for case 2 by 3, since there are 3 ways to select the number that goes in the good range (is it the first number picked, the 2nd, or th 3rd?)...

Comment: You need to multiply the result for case 4 by 3, since there are 3 ways to choose the element that goes in the bad range.

Comment: Last, I'm not sure how you got the result for case 5, but one way to do it is to first pick which element (first, second, or third?) goes in the lower bad group, then pick the one to go in the good group, then pick the one to go in the upper bad group. There are 6=3! ways to do this. Next, the probability the lower bad goes in the right place is (1/4), the probability the good element goes in the right place is (1/2), and the probability the upper bad goes in the right place is (1/4), giving us a total probability of 6*1/4*1/2*1/4=3/16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 2 you have only counted the cases where the first number you select is good.  You should multiply by $3$ for the three different positions the good number is in.  This adds $\frac 18$ to your total.  For case 4 you should multiply by $3$ for selecting which of the numbers is bad.  That multiplies adds $\frac 14$ to the total.  For case 5 you should multiply by $3$ to account for the ordering of the low, good, and high numbers.  This adds $\frac 1{8}$ to the total.  That brings the total to $1$ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Consider cases, based on the number of good numbers . . .

For the median to be good, we need at least one good number.

**Case $(1)$:**$\;$Exactly $1\;$good number.

  The probability of exactly $1\;$good number is: $\;\binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3=\frac{3}{8}$.
  The factor $\binom{3}{1}$ is needed to account for which of the $3$ selections is good.

  But we have to worry about the types of the selected bad numbers . . .

  The two bad numbers are either (low,high), (high,low), (low,low), (high,high), with all $4$ pairs equally likely.

  For the good number to be a median, we can only allow the  pairs (low,high), (high,low), hence, given that case $(1)$ occurs, the probability of a good median is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;$Exactly $2\;$good numbers.

  The probability of exactly $2\;$good numbers is: $\;\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3=\frac{3}{8}$.
  The factor $\binom{3}{2}$ is needed to account for which $2$ of the $3$ selections are good.

**Case $(3)$:**$\;3\;$good numbers.

  The probability of $3\;$good numbers. is: $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3=\frac{1}{8}$.

Of the three cases, cases $(2)$ and $(3)$ always yield a good median.

For case $(1)$, to get a good median, we need to apply the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus, summing the results for all three cases, the probability of a good median is
$$
\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}{\,\cdot\,}{\small{\frac{3}{8}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{3}{8}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{1}{8}}}\right)
=
{\small{\frac{11}{16}}}
$$